# Validating input in a React app

Tags: javascript, validation, react.js

I was writing some validation logic for a React-native app and thought I had so many bools flying around in my code!

Is there any way to reduce redundancy in this code or is this the best that can be done?

```
_validatePhone() {
    if (!validate.validatePhone(this.state.phone)) {
      this.setState({ phoneError: true });
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}

_validateName() {
    if (!validate.validateName(this.state.name)) {
      this.setState({ nameError: true });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  _validateForm() {
    this._resetErrors(); // Reset errors before validating
    if (!this._validateName()) {
      return false;
    } else if (!this._validatePhone()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_validateForm` can be reduced to

```
_validateForm() {
    this._resetErrors(); // Reset errors before validating
    return this._validateName() && this._validatePhone();
}
```